# Get available space on Gmail account via API python

Tags: gmail, imap, pop3

Is there a way(Api or anything..pop/imap in python) via which you can get to know the available space on your Gmail account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears GMail supports the [Quota Extension for IMAP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2087.txt), and at least some information is available that way.

On my account, I get this information:

```
  > a001 GETQUOTA ""
  < * QUOTA "" (STORAGE 72600 10601545)
```

The units are in kilobytes.  This means I'm using 72 megs, of a total of 10 gigabytes, which appears to match approximately what gmail.com is saying is the current amount per user.

Comment: This will help me, will check the IMAP implementation.