# Possible to get Quota (used & total space) on Gmail using ImapX 2?

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, imapx

Is it possible to get the used & total or free space for a Gmail account using ImapX 2?

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15390448 Gmail supports the [Quota Extension for IMAP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2087.txt), although I didn't see a way to send a custom command via ImapX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ImapX but here's a Perl script that reads a user's quota using GETQUOTAROOT.

./get_quota.pl imap.gmail.com:993 user password

usage 241047

quota 15728640

http://www.athensfbc.com/public/get_quota

-Rick

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  Unfortunately, ImapX does not allow me to send a IMAP command.

Comment: @AlienTechnology please see my [answer](http://imapx.codeplex.com/discussions/538565) in the thread you started yesterday. ImapX allows to send custom commands.

Comment: @Pavel - That solution will work for me.  If you'll post that answer here, I will select it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

ImapX allows to send custom commands using the `ImapClient.SendAndReceive` method.